# Twitter Oauth: How to validate and get user details through

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I followed https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing and I successfully got access token. Now I know I need to send get request to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json to get user details but I'm not getting how and where to put tokens I got.

I tried putting **Authorization** header as

> OAuth
>
> oauth_consumer_key="*oauth_consumer_key*",
>
> oauth_signature_method="*oauth_signature_method*",
>
> oauth_timestamp="1527943990", oauth_nonce="RicCiR6KbNa",oauth_version="1.0",
>
> oauth_signature="siKIF%2FMTFKCYokEsI7qBJrrHZHs%3D",
>
> oauth_token="*Access Token*",
>
> oauth_token_secret="*oauth_token_secret*"

But it gives

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 32,
            "message": "Could not authenticate you."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: which language are you using ? can you post some code ?

Comment: I'm not using any sdk. I'll be using Node but right now I'm using postman to get responses

Comment: I got it working in postman using OAuth 1.0 authentication with request headers. You just fill in all the fields from your developer account, some timestamp, a random 32 alphanumeric nonce and you're ready to get data.